# Why are we getting error while insert or update using SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle SQL developer for my Oracle database. In the newer version of SQL Developer, I am getting error while saving the data (insert/update) in a table using Ctrl + S, whereas there is no issue commit button in SQL Developer.

[image]

`SEVERE   678 236298  oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.EditableResultSetTableModel$SaveTaskListener$1  oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.getResult(RaptorTask.java:335)`

- OS - Windows 10
- Java - 1.8.0.241
- SQL Developer - 19+ (all versions higher than 19)

Comment: Can you share and example INSERT or UPDATE statement that is causing the error? also, what is the exact Java version that you have? SQL Developer version 19.2 requires Java version 1.8 update 121, so if you are using an old version of Java 8, I would try updating the version of Java installed on your machine. See the section **JDK Support** here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldev/sqldev-relnotes-v192.html

Comment: this is a known bug - please use the Commit button/kb shortcut instead